# Old Sci Fi book of short stories about future crimes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Back in the mid-70's I read a book that had a series of short stories relating various crimes based on technologies that would exist in the (then) future. There was one involving a head transplant between a man and an ape, one that involved a clone and so on.

Does anyone know what it could have been?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? To clarify are you looking for the book that contained the collection of stories or one of the stories in particular? The former may be off topic as too broad though I'm not 100% on that. Lastly, if you haven't already make sure to take the [tour]!

Comment: There are several future crime anthologies: Bova's "Future Crime" and Asimov/Greenberg's "The 13 Crimes of Science Fiction" for example.  The more detail you can give on the stories you remember, the easier it will be to find the right one.

Comment: I was going to say "Whatdunits" but that wasn't published until '92.  https://www.amazon.com/Whatdunits-Mike-Resnick/dp/0886775337

Comment: It doesn't appear to be Miriam Allen DeFord's "Space, Time and Crime" anthology- I've looked at my copy and there's no stories resembling those outlines at all.